# Rails3 Beginner - How to identify records with a specific word in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause

I am strugging to find a command that enables me to identify those records in an array which contain a specific word, and wondered if someone could point me in the correct direction.

Essentially I have names in one column and addresses in another.  I would now like to restrict the data to just those people in a certain city, so for example i want to show all those who live in London - i.e. 'London' must be contained within their address string.

Is it possible to use the WHERE and LIKE functions to do this somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about an array or a database table?

Comment: Sorry, I am used to using Matlab so call everything arrays.  I mean database, I defined using rails generate scaffold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
def SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :contains_city,
    lambda { |city| where("some_models.address LIKE ?","%"+city+"%" ) }
end

#Usage:
records = some_instance_of_model.contains_city "London"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use LIKE keyword to get this sort of information, but you would be much better of if, instead of using single field for storing address, you used multiple :

```
 Users           Addresses             Countries
-------------   -------------------   -------------
 user_id         address_id            country_id
 address_id      country_id            titile
 full_name       city_id
                 street_and_number
```

There are many addresses in single country/city. And you can have more then one person living in same city or even have the same street address.

Anyway, this would much better way to organize your data, especially since LIKE is really really slow.

P.S.  scaffolding is for quick prototyping and not for production code.

Comment: That's very useful thanks, as a final qn then, out of interest what would you use instead of scaffolding?

Comment: afaik , scaffolding itself is part of Rails development process, you there is no "instead" there. Point is , that you should not relay on scaffolded code. When you start to write your own code, you should not hesitate to tear the scaffolds down. It's "throw-away" code, so you should use it like that.